# Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 10.04. -Access Forbidden Error 403

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, virtualhost

Operating System: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Downloaded and installed Xampp for linux 1.8.1 in /opt

When I go to localhost I get the standard xampp start page, everyting works, except phpmyadmin which I fixed by adding the "Required all Granted" line to extra/httpd-xampp.conf

```
# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,Deny
    Allow from all
#cahg 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I want to develop multiple sites so I have set up Virtual hosts using what I think is the standard method.

1. Include extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in my httpd.conf file
2. In the extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file added a virtual host container.
   3.Add the following to /etc/hosts file

   127.0.1.1       site1

I must have done this first part right because it is working but I am getting the following error in my web browser when I navigate to 'site 1'

```
    Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

site1
Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

and this error in my ErrorLog

```
[Fri Nov 16 17:14:22.481075 2012] [core:error] [pid 14465] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.1.1:46687] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/andrew/websites/site1') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

The solution I have tried is adding this Directory block to my httpd-vhosts.conf file in directory tags with /home/andrew/websites/site as and attribute.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Without fully understanding what it does because it was a solution I found and in httpd.conf it states `"You must explicitly permit access to web content directories in other <Directory> blocks below."`

My Question is: What is the best way to allow apache to access the files for my various virtual hosts?
Note: in httpd.conf user is nobody and group is set to nogroup.

Answer (score 2):

first change user nobody to your ubuntu username in httpd.conf

then at the end of httpd.conf:

```
# XAMPP
Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

second make sure your virtual folders belongs to your username (you'll have to change ownership of phpmyadmin if my memory works)

then create alias in httpd-xampp.conf :

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin"
Alias /youralias "/path/to/folder"
```

then allow directory in that same httpd-xampp.conf :

```
<Directory "/path/to/folder">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

bye bye 403